# Pymongo is it possible to insert one with insert_many?

Tags: python, pymongo

This may sound like a dumb question but I was working with pymongo and wrote the following function to insert documents and was wondering if the insert_many method would also work for one record inserts, that way I wouldn't need another function in case I was just inserting one record.

This is my function:

```
def insert_records(list_of_documents: list, collection):
    i = collection.insert_many(list_of_documents)
    print(len(i.inserted_ids), " documents inserted!")
```

When I insert one it throws an error:

```
post1 = {"_id":0, "user_name":"Jack"}
insert_records(list(post1), stackoverflow)
```

*TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping*

I know I can use insert_one() for this purpose, I was just wondering if it was possible to do everything with insert_many(), as the original insert() method is deprecated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `post1` is a dict when you use `list(post1)` you have a list of keys:

```
>>> list(post1)
['_id', 'user_name']
```

Use instead:

```
>>> [post1]
[{'_id': 0, 'user_name': 'Jack'}]
```

So:

```
insert_records([post1], stackoverflow)
```